# Verify that a path doesn't contain . or .. or // and doesn't end with /

Tags: c, validation

This is actually a [function from the first commit of the git source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290/update-cache.c#L199), for the purpose stated in the title:

> ```
> static int verify_path(char *path)
> {
>   char c;
>
>   goto inside;
>   for (;;) {
>       if (!c)
>           return 1;
>       if (c == '/') {
> inside:
>           c = *path++;
>           if (c != '/' && c != '.' && c != '\0')
>               continue;
>           return 0;
>       }
>       c = *path++;
>   }
> }
> ```

I was checking if there was an alternate way to implement this without the `goto` statement and ended up with this function:

```
static int verify_path(char *path)
{
    char c = '/';

    do {
        if (c == '/') {
            c = *path++;
            if (c == '/' || c == '.' || c == '\0')
                return 0;
        }
    } while ((c = *path++));

    return 1;
}
```

Do you see any problems with the new function? Is it missing anything from the original?

Let us please avoid discussing about `goto`.

---

**Sample list of invalid path names:**

- /path/to/file
- ../path/to/file
- path//to/file
- path/../to/file
- path/./to/file
- path/to/.file
- path/to/file/

Comment: I don't see why `"/path/to/file"` should be invalid. The original function does reject it, but the description says it should not.

Comment: @WilliamMorris: In the context of git, the function should allow only files within the folder that is being tracked so absolute paths should be rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Much better

I like your version much better than the original.  I don't see any cases you missed - it appears to work the same as the original function.  The only comment I have is that the `path` argument should be marked `const`.  But maybe you aren't allowed to change that.

Answer (score 3):

Basically like [@JS1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/58193/js1) stated in his [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/99069/29371) your version is better, but can still be improved.

IMHO you should distinguish between an invalid char at the start of the path and the occurance of `/.`, `//` and `\0`.

By using a `while` instead of a `do..while` loop you can use a guard clause to `continue` if `c != '/'` which reduces the horizontal spacing.

```
static int verify_path(char *path)
{
    char c = *path++;

    if (c == '/' || c == '.' || c == '\0') {
        return 0;
    }

    while ((c = *path++)) {

        if (c != '/') {
            continue;
        }

        c = *path++;
        if (c == '/' || c == '.' || c == '\0') {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

by extracing the check for the invalid chars to a separate method this will remove the code duplication

```
static int is_invalid_char(char c)
{
    return (c == '/' || c == '.' || c == '\0');
}
```

which then leads to

```
static int verify_path(char *path)
{
    char c = *path++;

    if (is_invalid_char(c)) {
        return 0;
    }

    while ((c = *path++)) {

        if (c != '/') {
            continue;
        }

        c = *path++;
        if (is_invalid_char(c)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I also have added braces `{}` arround single statements of the `if`'s, because it makes the code less error prone.